# Rotate plane to make it parallel to another plane

Tags: three.js, geometry

I've got 2 planes, the first one is given by 3 points in world space coordinates, and it's constructed using custom `Geometry()` and one face (in other words: it's just a triangle in 3D space).
The second one is constructed from `PlaneBufferGeometry()` which is parallel to the `xy` plane.
How to rotate the red one to make it parallel to the first one ???

Illustration:
[image]

My algorithm is the following:

1. Get rotation axis through plane's normal vectors
2. Compute the angle between them
3. Create and apply to the red plane rotation matrix using axis and angle

In code:

```
var v1, v2, v3, geom, mat, plane3mesh, redPlaneMesh;            
geom = new THREE.Geometry();
geom.vertices.push(v1, v2, v3);
var face = new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2);
geom.faces.push(face);            
geom.computeFaceNormals();
geom.computeVertexNormals();
plane3mesh = //...create mesh

geom = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(700, 700);
redPlaneMesh = //...create red plane mesh 
var redPlaneNormal = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);            
var axis = face.normal.clone().cross(redPlaneNormal);
var angle = Math.acos(face.normal.dot(redPlaneNormal) ); // lengths are unit so no need for division

var rotationWorldMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
rotationWorldMatrix.makeRotationAxis(axis.normalize(), angle);
redPlaneMesh.matrix.multiply(rotationWorldMatrix); 
redPlaneMesh.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix(redPlaneMesh.matrix);
```

But it gives a wrong result, which is this:
[image]

What is wrong with my algorithm and what are the different solutions?

Comment: Have you tried rotation by negative `angle` ? (acos doesn't consider rotation direction)

Comment: @Mbo just tried with negative angle and it worked ! damn ! what is the explanation of that ?

Comment: @MBo seems like it's working with negative angle

Comment: @ampawd Try plane.lookAt( triangle_normal );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`acos` function gives absolute angle as result. So, for example, result `Pi/4` may mean both "rotate A by Pi/4" and "rotate B by Pi/4".

Your axis is calculated through the first and the second normals, so N1, N2 and Ax vectors form "right-handed" triplet. It seems that in this case you always have to negate angle sign to transform needed normal into other one.